# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getPassword(Ljava/lang/String;)[C

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform

Problem statement :
While creating the Dataset of file located at bucket(GCP) from local spark java code with the following version of jar/lib then getting exception.

Exception 1: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getPassword(Ljava/lang/String;)[C"

Getting above exception when use the following set of jar/lib.

```
Spark - org.apache.spark
spark-core_2.11
spark-sql_2.11
Hadoop - org.apache.hadoop
hadoop-auth 3.3.1
hadoop-hdfs 3.3.1
hadoop-common 3.3.1
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core 3.3.1
hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient 3.3.1
hadoop-nfs 3.3.1
hadoop-client 3.3.1
com.google.cloud.bigdataoss
gcs-connector-hadoop2-latest
```

Following is the local java source code

```
SparkConf objSparkConf = new SparkConf();
objSparkConf.setAppName("Spark");
objSparkConf.setMaster("local[*]");
objSparkConf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem");
objSparkConf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS");
objSparkConf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true");
objSparkConf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "D:\\GCP\\test-environment-json-keyfile.json");
objSparkConf.set("fs.defaultFS", "gs://hudi-bucket");
JavaSparkContext spContext = new JavaSparkContext(objSparkConf);
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test_Spark").getOrCreate();
String sFileUrl = "gs://test/2/4/CRUNCH_JOB.3d997666-7d58-4ee8-bf42-a30438983ccb.20211025_072502";
Dataset<Row> dataSet1 = sparkSession.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load(sFileUrl);
```

Comment: Last I checked, Spark doesn't use Hadoop3 dependencies, so you should remove these as Spark includes those itself and using other versions will cause such errors

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was caused by an older version of hadoop-core (1.2.1 instead of 2.6.5) which was brought in as a transitive Maven dependency. You can also set a breakpoint and check which jar and version exactly your class `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` comes from.